# 301 redirect a single page in Gatsby

Tags: .htaccess, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I installed the npm package "gatsby-plugin-htaccess" and added it to the gatsby-config.js, it worked fine and gave me a .htaccess file that tidies up the url when I publish the build.

Now, I want to permanently 301  redirect some pages so I get the following result;
https://example.com/old-page/ redirects to https://example.com/new-page/

What is the syntax for "gatsby-plugin-htaccess" or "gatsby-plugin-htaccess-redirects" to get this to work?

I’ve tried following the documentation but there isn’t much of it -
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-htaccess-redirects

gatsby-plugin-htaccess seems to allow redirects but it also says they are not automatically integrated and recommend using gatsby-plugin-htaccess-redirects -
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you should call [`createRedirect`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/actions/#createRedirect) from your `gatsby-node.js` to set up a redirect. `gatsby-plugin-htaccess-redirects` will then use that information to add it to the .htaccess file.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I’ve been playing with this over the weekend and still cannot get it to work. 

I amended and added the code from createRedirect to gatsby-node.js. 
I added gatsby-plugin-meta-redirect to gatsby-config.js. 
Also included the example code from gatsby-plugin-htaccess-redirects.